Working with Python files in azure Databricks
I am facing one challenge in my project work.
I have done all my project development previously in VS code.
The new requirement is I want deploy everything into databricks. I have created a workspace - DUMMY. Inside the DUMMY  workspace i have manually created the same folder structure which I have maintained in VS CODE and imported all the Python files also. I have some config.yaml file also those files also I have imported manually.
I want to know how I can make my Python files working in databricks environment similarly how we do VS CODE?
what steps can I follow.

did you go over this doc?
https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/vscode-ext/run.html

What is your expected outcome? Please add some samples you wanted to use in databricks.

Hi @JayashankarGS , the requirements are how we run a python file in vs code like python main.py, and in that main.py file suppose we are doing import from multiple files. I want to know how can we develop such thing in databricks environment.  Do  i need to convert all the codes in python into spark and write it in notebook format or can i use the same python files. Rest file structure details i have already shared in the question

You can follow the below steps you can follow:

You need to create a new Databricks project   Open Visual Studio Code,Next click File > Open Folder and Open a new, empty folder on your local development machine. Click on the Databricks logo icon in the sidebar to open the Databricks extension. In the Configuration view, you need to choose "Migrate to a Databricks Project."

This will open the Command Palette to configure your Databricks workspace.

You will get the databricks host from databricks url. Choose an
authentication profile for the project.  Know more regarding the authentication setup guide for the Databricks extension in Visual Studio Code.

Click Select a cluster or click the gear (Configure cluster) icon. In the Command Palette, select the name of the cluster that you created previously. Click the play icon (Start Cluster) if it is not already started.

Next you can Create and run Python code & Run the code as a job


Reference: Tutorial: Run Python on a cluster and as a job using the Databricks extension for Visual Studio Code
